# simultaneous tomcat cluster where each node in the cluster serves different data

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat6

Reading through [this article](http://www.richardnichols.net/2010/08/5-minute-guide-clustering-apache-tomcat/) my understanding is a Tomcat cluster contains multiple "nodes" (or instances) of Tomcat.  However, I get the impression that the user only sees data served by one of these nodes (i.e. the user cannot see data served by all of these nodes simultaneously).  Therein lies my problem.

I need the user to see data served by all nodes at the same time because each node contains different information.

For example,

If **NodeA** lists out

```
/nodeA/file1.txt
/nodeA/file2.txt
```

**NodeB** lists out

```
/nodeB/file3.txt
/nodeB/file4.txt
```

With Tomcat clustering as the article explains it, the user will only see one of the above two lists, but not both.  But I want the user to see the full list of 4 files (file1.txt, file2.txt,file3.txt, and file4.txt).

Will Tomcat cluster achieve this for me? Is there a way to configure cluster to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each HTTP request is handled by a single Tomcat node. The purpose of clustering is twofold: first, so that your site doesn't go down entirely is a Tomcat node fails, and second, to improve throughput by having more than one node handling requests. Having Tomcat nodes "talk amongst themselves" to handle a request would compromise both purposes, by making request processing much slower and by making it impossible to answer a request properly if a node goes down.

Data that needs to be shared between nodes needs to be moved off of Tomcat. For your example, you could use a shared filesystem like NFS that each node reads to get the full file list. There are also cluster filesystems like  [GlusterFS](http://www.gluster.org/) or [Lustre](http://lustre.opensfs.org/) if you need something with better performance than NFS.

Comment: We are currently using NFS but it's too slow for us.  We are trying to stay away from it.  Is there any other way besides NFS?

Comment: Definitely. Nowadays there are lots of options for distributed filesystems. [GlusterFS](http://www.gluster.org/), [Lustre](http://lustre.opensfs.org/), for starters.